# Using Tuple.IsMappedBy with generic Tuple

Tags: scala, generics, tuples, scala-3

Let's say I have a generic class

```
class Box[V](var value: V)
```

and I want to write a generic method with a single parameter that accepts tuples like `(Box[?], Box[?], …, Box[?])`. A naïve approach would be

```
def f[ATupleOfBoxes <: Tuple: Tuple.IsMappedBy[Box]](arg: ATupleOfBoxes): Unit = {}
```

At first glance, it seems to work. However, any usage with non-prescripted size fails:

```
f((Box(7), Box("hello"))) //< this works
f((Box('q'), Box(false), Box(2.5))) //< this too

def g[ATuple <: Tuple](a: ATuple): Unit = {
  val b = a.map([anItemType] => (item: anItemType) => Box(item))
  f(b) //< this fails…
}
```

…with [the message](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bh3QisVpRqyW8hjdc5bdvg)

> Cannot prove that Tuple.Map[(a : ATuple), Box] =:= scala.Tuple.Map[scala.Tuple.InverseMap[Tuple.Map[(a : ATuple), Box], Box], Box].
>
> where:    ATuple is a type in method g with bounds <: Tuple
>
> Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:
>
> trying to reduce  Tuple.Map[(a : ATuple), Box]
>   failed since selector (a : ATuple)
>   does not match  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
>   and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
>   Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining case
>
> case h *: t => Box[h] *: scala.Tuple.Map[t, Box]

Any solution/workaround for that?

Just for the sake of experiment, I tried to remove method parameters and to pass types explicitly, but the result is [the same](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RTHmoaItTzCtKrPWDrhhag):

```
class Box[V](var value: V)

def f[ATupleOfBoxes <: Tuple: Tuple.IsMappedBy[Box]](): Unit = {}

f[(Box[Int], Box[String])]() //< this works
f[(Box[Char], Box[Boolean], Box[Double])]() //< this too

def g[ATuple <: Tuple](): Unit = {
  type B = Tuple.Map[ATuple, Box]
  f[B]() //< this fails
}
```

> Cannot prove that B =:= scala.Tuple.Map[scala.Tuple.InverseMap[B, Box], Box].

Comment: A workaround:  change g to inline method, i.e. `inline def g[ATuple <: Tuple](a: ATuple): Unit = ...`